# How can I write to the textfile with "while"?

Tags: python, file-io

```
while 1:
    text_file = open("write_it.txt", "w")
    word = input("Please add to a text file: ")
```

What else do I need to add to make my code run properly?

Comment: From the question and especially from the comments below by the OP, this looks like a homework question with _no_ learning effort on the part of the OP. I guess this invites closing, unless someone feels otherwise.

Comment: All of you: Stop bloody using "while 1". Python has had booleans for ages.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: While true, perhaps they should read a tutorial before that.

Comment: @S.Lott: it's "while True", not "While true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
text_file = open("write_it.txt", "w")
while 1:
    word = input("Please add to a text file: ")
    if not word:
        break
    text_file.write(word)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but that open statement inside of the while couldn't be affecting its behaviour?
Have you tried just moving it out of while loop?

Comment: i mean i need to continue this code 
to make a program thats writes everything to the "write_it.txt

Comment: i dont really understand, i tried to use "a" for open file and add somthing there but still its a blank txt file. please can you give me a full code of that programm

Comment: IF you get Aaron's code and instead of: 
word = input("Please add to a text file: ")
you use:
word = raw_input("Please add to a text file: ")
It should work