# Appending to a text file

Tags: python, text-files, raw-input

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Confused with appending  to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237683/confused-with-appending-to-text-file)
>   [How can I write to the textfile with “while”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237154/how-can-i-write-to-the-textfile-with-while)

```
text_file = open("write_it.txt", "a")
while 1:
    word = raw_input("Please add to a text file: ")
    if not word:
        break
    text_file.write(word)
text_file.close()
```

this code adds text to the text file, but not accurately how can i make it accurately?

Comment: what is the exact problem? What does "not accurately" mean?

Comment: Stop asking the exact same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237683/confused-with-appending-to-text-file-closed; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237154/how-can-i-write-to-the-textfile-with-while).

Comment: it adds to the text file not accurately without spaces, and i want it to add with spaces and in each row all the time i add somthing new

Comment: Dominic its not the same question

Comment: sorry for closing as duplicate, after last comment from user270308 this question clearly is a different programming problem than the last.

Comment: @user270308 - It's not now you've explained a bit more what you mean. Can you give us a sample of you running the program - perhaps with the expected results and the actual results? If you do that I (and probably others) will vote to reopen.

Comment: @David - agreed - I probably banged on the close link too quickly - I just recognised the code from last time around.

Comment: ok when i run this program for example i add word "sugar"
next time i add word "milk" in my text file i can see that it created two words without the spaces "sugarmilk" and i wanted to be like that
sugar
milk

can you please help me to resolve this prob) thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting the code to magically add spaces? If you want them in the file, add them :) do text_file.write(" ") before each new word (if it is not the first word)